# C# ServerManager, need admin right for IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis, privileges, administrator

Hi i have some problem with ServerManager in C#
i want to get all sites from IIS
for example:

```
static ServerManager iismanager = new ServerManager();

foreach (var site in iismanager.Sites)
{
     var temp = new ToolStripMenuItem();
     temp.Text = site.ToString();
     temp.Click += new EventHandler(Change_State);
}
```

Now if i run this without admin right i got access denied.

So my question ;)
There is any option to force admin right without [UAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) prompt?

Comment: You need to use Impersonation. Been asked/answered a number of times.. [lmgtfy](https://lmgtfy.app/?q=c%23+iis+impersonate+user)

Comment: Manage sites on IIS is a very important work. So IIS doesn't allow non-admin to get information of sites unless feature delegation. You need to run it with admin right.

Comment: So i need to be friends with UAC ;)